# $x+ix=i$ solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

3 years without math exercises , today I found a question in [Quora](https://fr.quora.com/Si-x-ix-i-quest-ce-que-x) about the solution of $x+ix =i$.

So I reasoned this way :

\begin{align} x+ix=i &\implies x=i−ix &\\
& \implies x=i(1−x) &\\
& \implies x/(1−x)=i\\
&\implies x^2/(1−x)^2=−1 \\
&\implies x^2=−[(1−x)^2]\\
& \implies x^2=−[1−2x+x^2] \\
&\implies x^2=−x^2+2x−1\\
&\implies 2x^2−2x+1=0\\
&\implies x^2−x+(1/2)=0
\end{align}
$$
a=1\quad b=−1 \quad c=1/2\\
\delta=b^2−4ac =−1=i^2
$$
so

$$x_1=(−b−i)/2∗a=(1−i)/2 \\
x_2=(−b+i)/2∗a=(1+i)/2$$

However the solution, as in site, is only $(1+i)/2$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first thing when you write such an equation is to specify in which set you want your solution to be. So, is $x$ supposed to be real or complex?

Comment: complex of course, i know there is no solution in R

Comment: Ok. You should write that (of couse). And what you write there is totally unreadable.

Comment: Squaring both sides introduces a spurious solution!

Comment: @Matteo is that make the equation resolving wrong  ? if yes why ?

Comment: Below someone gave a much faster approach. However be careful because squaring both sides of an equation doesn't give an *equivalent* equation.

Comment: @Matteo so we always shouldn't do squaring  in equation-resolving  ?

Comment: a=b => a²=b² this is right

Comment: If you do so, you must fix some conditions in order to avoid introducing invalid solutions

Comment: Consider that $x^2/(1-x)^2=-1$ implies $x/(1-x)=\pm i$!

Comment: @A.HADDAD the problem is that $a^2 = b^2$ does **not** imply $a=b$. So, **it is not an equivalent equation**.

Comment: When you square an equation you potentially introduce new solutions which are not solutions of the original equation. It is sometimes a useful way of making progress, but the rule is "always check whether the solutions you find are solutions of the original equation".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's keep things simple. Suppose you are given $$x=1$$
Squaring both sides gives $$x^2=1$$
And the solutions of the quadratic equation $x^2=1$ are $x=1$ and $x=-1$. So the squared equation has more solutions that the original equation!

Whenever you square both sides of an equation like this, you must always go back to the original equation at the end, to check whether your solutions are still valid. In this case, you see that the solution $x=-1$ is not a valid solution of the equation $x=1$, so you reject it.

In your case, you must check both your solutions $x_1$ and $x_2$. You will find that only $x_2$ is a valid solution of the original equation. So you must discard $x_1$.

Having said that, there is no need to square both sides to solve your equation. Just write it as $$x(1+i)=i$$
and divide both sides by $1+i$.

Answer (score 1):

$$x=\frac{i}{1+i}=\frac{i(1-i)}{(1+i)(1-i)}=\frac{i+1}{2}$$

Comment: yes  i know that way , but my question is about my way why it's wrong ?

Comment: Try as much as possible not to change the equation

Answer (score 1):

Here’s what is wrong in your method. When you square both side by writing $\frac{x}{1−x}=i\Longrightarrow \frac{x²}{(1−x)²}=−1$ you have admitted others solutions which are not necessarily solution of the first equation. With this method you may verify which ,of the solution you have at the end, is a good one.

E.g
$$x=1\Longrightarrow x^2=1\Longrightarrow x=1, \text{ or } x=-1.$$ Thus we have to eliminate $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

$[1].$ Suppose $A\implies B\implies C \implies x\in \{0,1\}.$ You cannot conclude, from this, that $x\in \{0,1\}\implies A.$ This does not mean that it isn't useful to use one-way implications. It's very useful but it's not the whole story. You have $A\implies x\in \{0,1\}$ and then  you may find

(i).  $x=0\implies \neg A$ and $x=1\implies \neg A,$ and conclude that $A$ is false for all $x,$ OR

(ii). $x=0 \implies A$ and $x=1\implies  \neg A,$ and conclude that $A\iff x=0,$ OR

(iii). $x=0\implies \neg A$ and $x=1\implies A,$ and conclude that $A\iff x=1,$ OR

(iv) $x=0\implies A$ and $x=1\implies A,$ and conclude that $A\iff (x=0 \lor x=1).$

$[2].$ Let $a,b \in \Bbb R.$ Then $a+ib \ne 0$ iff $a,b$ are not both $0.$ And if  $a+ib\ne 0 $ then $a+ib$ has a multiplicative inverse $(a/r-ib/r)=(a-ib)/r$ where $r=a^2+b^2.$ Because $$(a+ib)(a-ib)/r=(a^2-i^2b^2)/r=(a^2+b^2)/r=1.$$ So if $x,y,z \in \Bbb C$ and $z\ne 0$ then $x=y\iff xz=yz.$ (Just as when $x,y,z\in \Bbb R$ and $z\ne 0$).

If $a=b=1$ then $r= a^2+b^2=2$ so $1/(a+ib) =(a-ib)/r=(1-i)/2.$

Therefore $$x+ix= i\iff  x(1+i)=i\iff$$ $$\iff x\cdot (1+i)[1/(1+i)]=i\cdot[1/(1+i)] \iff$$ $$\iff x\cdot 1=i\cdot [(1-i)/2]\iff$$ $$\iff x=[i-i^2]/2=[i-(-1)]/2=(i+1)/2. $$

Notice the implications are two-way so there is nothing more to do.

In brief, solving a linear equation in one variable $(x)$ in $\Bbb C$ is done just the way you do it in $\Bbb R.$